# Xamarin.Forms. Is there any way to split the Screen into 2 different pages (CarouselPage & Page)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am trying to get a Page in Xamarin.Forms with a swappable "boxView" in the middle. Pretty much the same that the carouselPage does, but not in the whole screen but just a small rectangle inside my main Page.
Is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box I'd say since it is a Carousel*Page*. Said that you can still implement it by yourself (using a Custom Renderer, View, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me an example of custom Renderer that is swapping a different box views as they were different pages? I am not finding any thing similar.

Comment: No idea out of my head, sorry, but if it is possible in Android then you can wrap that functionality into a Render.